# Calculate average per day based on the difference of the values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max, average

I have a table:

| value | updated_at | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-1-1 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 2022-1-1 12:00:30 | 2 |
| 20 | 2022-1-1 12:02:30 | 3 |

What I want to do is to get an average based on the `updated_at` column difference, and the values of course.

So, I guess the formula should be:

`(sumof((value2 - value1) * (date2 - date1))) / (dateLast - dateFirst)` where 1 and 2 means for each two rows when we traverse from the first to the last item. eg for this table we'll have:

First and second row: `(value2 - value1) * (date2 - date1)` = `(10 - 5) * (30 (seconds))` = `150`

for second and third row: `(20 - 10) * 120` = 1200

So the result is:

`(1200 + 150) / (2022-1-1 12:02:30 - 2022-1-1 12:00:00) = 9`

I probably can get this working with a self JOIN on ID and ID + 1 and I also can do the diff of last and first date, but I can't do them both in the same query! I have no idea how to do that, is this even possible to be done in a single query?

---

Update

My MySql version is 5.6

Comment: Are there gaps between the ids? Also, what is your version of MySql?

Comment: Have you looked at using sum()over() and lag() = MySql8 required

Comment: Or try using `with` to gather the data and then it should be easy.

Comment: @forpas not really, but now that you mentioned that I'm curious how that could be done I can't think of a way to do that self join but with gap ids!!

Comment: @Stu Should have mentioned I'm talking about mysql 5.6 sorry :(

Comment: @maraca that's also for mysql 8 I'd suppose :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `LAG()` window function to get each row's previous  values and then aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         value - LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY updated_at) dif_value,
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(updated_at) OVER (ORDER BY updated_at)) dif_time
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT SUM(dif_value * dif_time) / 
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(updated_at)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(updated_at))) result 
FROM cte;
```

For previous versions and if there are no gaps between the ids, use a self join:

```
SELECT SUM(dif_value * dif_time) / 
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(updated_at)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(updated_at))) result 
FROM (
  SELECT t1.*,
         t1.value - t2.value dif_value,
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.updated_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.updated_at) dif_time
  FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID + 1
) t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e703a4507997e8f2631a884253166cbf).

Comment: Thank you so much this is really precious to me I'm sorry I didn't mention mysql 5.6 was the target :(

Comment: @SteveMoretz the 2nd query works in version 5.6

Comment: Wow!! You're a genius !!! I got my answer with that brilliant creativity of yours in the select statement however I would love to know (out of curiosity) what should I have done in case there were gaps in the ids? Would be great if you give me some pointers! Thanks again

Comment: @SteveMoretz if there are gaps between the ids, one way to get the previous id of each row would be with a correlated subquery in the ON clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=223d53ff19953f7dcee25a830c28c37e